# Migrating to Styled-Components with global SASS variables in React

Tags: reactjs, sass, styled-components

I'm trying to slowly introduce Styled-Components into my existing codebase which relies heavily on global SASS variables (partials imported into a `main.scss`).

How do I reference the SCSS variables? The following doesn't work:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: $color-blue;
`;

export default Button;
```

Am I approaching this from the wrong way?

Comment: You won't have access to the SASS variables outside of your SASS file. Instead you'll have to define those in a constants file somewhere as an object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variables play a very important role in `.scss` or `.sass`, but the functionality cannot be extended outside the file.

Instead, you have to create a separate `.js` file *(**For example:** variable.js)* and define all your variables as an object.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote up an article about solving this very issue. https://medium.com/styled-components/getting-sassy-with-sass-styled-theme-9a375cfb78e8

Essentially, you can use the excellent [sass-extract](https://github.com/jgranstrom/sass-extract) library along with [sass-extract-loader](https://github.com/jgranstrom/sass-extract-loader) and the [sass-extract-js](https://github.com/adamgruber/sass-extract-js) plugin to bring your global Sass variables into your app as a theme object.

Comment: Great article, thanks for taking the time! :) I'd just suggest maintaining consistency between filenames, for ease of understanding. In your code snippet, when you create the `const theme = ...` variable, the SASS filename is `vars.scss`, but later in the article you mention a file called `variables.scss`. Being the newbie that I am, I wasn't sure whether I should replace `vars.scss` by my filename or if it was some command-specific path :)

Answer (score 12):

Pardon me if this is an old question but I thought I chip in on how I use CSS variables for both my `.scss` and `styled-components` when the need arises.

**Basic Usage:**

Declaring a global variable (preferably at `_variables.scss`)

```
:root {
    --primary-color: #fec85b;
}
```

Using the global property:

```
.button {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

or

```
const Button = styled.button`
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
`;
```

Please pay attention to the double line `--`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the ThemeProvider component. I'm also moving away from sass and towards styled components. The Theming with styled-components uses React's context api and is quite nice. Check out the this documentation [Styled Components Theming](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming).