# Using variables from SASS to styled components and file scss in Vue

Tags: vue.js, sass, styled-components

Hi I have file `_variables.sass`:

```
:root {
   --fontBook: 'Avenir LT W04_45 Book1475512';
   $colors: (
      primary: #ef4f10,
   );
}
```

I added `:root`, because I need to use variable in styled components ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57701937/6678345)).

I have a problem with object `$colors`. When I use:

`font-family: var(--fontBook);`

Font changes correctly, but when I want use $colors->primary:

`color: var(map-get($colors, primary));`

then color does not change.

How I can use `$colors->primary` in styled compoennts ?

***Edit:***

I only found this resolve:

```
:root {
   --fontBook: #{$fontBook};
   --colorPrimary: #{map-get($colors, primary)};
}
```

but it is not a satisfactory solution to my problem.